# generating a line chart with the Time (with AM/PM) on Y axis

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, charts, amcharts

I need to draw a graph whose Y axis would be the Time in "AM/PM" format.

I tried different available libraries like : [amcharts](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/). But I am not able to display the chart in AM/PM time wise, it's only accepting the decimal values.

Here is my code snipped :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Chart example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="./js/charts js/amcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js">      
  <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

  </head>      
  <style>
   #chartdiv {
        width   : 100%;
       height   : 500px;
    }
   </style>


  <!-- Chart code -->
  <script>
  var chartData = generateChartData();

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
"type": "serial",
"theme": "light",
"legend": {
    "useGraphSettings": true
},
"dataProvider": chartData,
"synchronizeGrid":true,
"valueAxes": [{
    "id":"v1",
    "axisColor": "#FF6600",
    "axisThickness": 2,
    "axisAlpha": 1,
    "position": "left"
}],
"graphs": [{
    "valueAxis": "v1",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "bullet": "round",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "Reports Printing Time",
    "valueField": "reportsPrintingTime",
    "fillAlphas": 0,
    "xField": "dateOfReportGen",
    "yField": "timeOfReportGen"
}, {
    "valueAxis": "v2",
    "lineColor": "#FF6600",
    "bullet": "square",
    "bulletBorderThickness": 2,
    "hideBulletsCount": 30,
    "title": "SLA Time",
    "valueField": "slaTime",
    "fillAlphas": 0
}],
"chartScrollbar": {},
"chartCursor": {
    "cursorPosition": "mouse"
},
"categoryField": "date",
"categoryAxis": {
    "parseDates": true,
    "axisColor": "#DADADA",
    "minorGridEnabled": true
},
"export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "position": "bottom-right"
 }
 });

 chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
 zoomChart();

function generateChartData() {
var chartData = [];
var firstDate = new Date();
firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate()-10);

    var reportsPrintingTime = ['9:30 AM','8:25 AM','11:05 AM','7:45 AM','9:25 AM','8:30 AM','9:10 AM','7:20 AM','9:55 AM','8:42 AM'];
    var slaTime = 10;    

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 

   //JUST FOR GETTING THE NEXT DATE VALUE
    var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);         

    chartData.push({
        date: newDate,
        reportsPrintingTime: reportsPrintingTime[i],
        slaTime: slaTime           
    });
  }
return chartData;
}

function zoomChart(){
chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 20, chart.dataProvider.length 
- 1);
}

</script>
<body>    
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
</body>
```

just wondering if anyone could suggest me as what's going wrong here. Any better way to achieve this ? I would highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can format dates using AmCharts following this options in V3: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/formatting-dates/

Considering AmCharts is working on the version 4, I also recommend you to check https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-date-time/ in case you would like to try the latest version.

There are few things you need to notice:

**Date format**

Make sure you have [dataDateFormat](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#dataDateFormat) set that matches the string in your data. You don't need to have your hours using AM/PM there. You can do that when parsing the label.

**Minimum period**

By default `CategoryAxis` minimum period is set as `"DD"`. You will need to change that to `"mm"` to show minutes.

**Formatting the label**

You can use `CategoyAxis` [labelFunction](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelFunction) to parse the label such as in:

```
"labelFunction": function (label, date) {
    return AmCharts.formatDate(date, "L:NN A");
}
```

Please check this example: https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1eb91c49e4c73cc42a3a31ab859ccc5b